# Symfony routing mapping

Tags: symfony, routes, twig

I've checked out http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html and couldn't find anything there, so I assume it's not possible but I figured I'll ask in case it is.

Is it possible to map a parameter in the route to another parameter. For example:

route.yml:

```
my_route:
  path: /{object_id}
  magic: map id:object_id
```

index.twig

```
{{path('my_route', {'id': 5})}}
```

So if I pass `id` through, will it be converted or mapped to `object_id`?

Answer (score 2):

Not quite sure, but this one is probably what you need:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/controllers.html#using-the-paramconverter

It'll automatically query for Doctrine entity with given id. But be careful, this isn't a solution for something non-trivial.

Comment: The ParamConverter will usually take an id, and return a fully built entity instead, ready to use in the controller. As we can inject anything inside a ParamConverter, it could receive the request and we can gather all route params from there. This is tricky....but don't think there are other ways to go